# working with merged core data models

Tags: core-data, models

I have an application that uses two merged core data models mapped to two different data stores (both are Sqlite stores) via use of model configurations (each unique configuration within each model is mapped to its own data store). The persistent store coordinator does a good job in saving relevant data into a correct store. However, the problem is that when the stores initially created by core data on very first save operation their data schemas look absolutely identically and correspond to a union of the two merged models. 
Is there any way to control core data so it creates the stores solely based on the configuration/model mapped into that store?

Answer (score 0):

I guess not, because if core data can generate partially schemas into different persistent store then it might destroy the relationships between them and thus cause problems. At least in current stage i dont think Apple tends to complete this.